# C++ sort array by private variable

Tags: c++

I have this class

```
Class VehicleTwoD
{
private:
doubleArea;
}
```

so I want to sort by doubleArea;

at my main.cpp

I got

```
int main()
{
VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];
sort(vehicletwod[0], vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]);

for (int i=0;i<vehicleCounter;vehicleCounter++)
    {
cout << "Vehicle " << i << end;
cout << vehicletwod[i]->toDisplay() << endl;
    }
}

Below is my operator overload at Vehicle.h


bool VehicleTwoD::operator<(const VehicleTwoD& rhs) const
{
return area > rhs.area;
}
```

When I try run the program, I get error on runtime - Segmentation core dump fault.

Assuming my Vehicle Counter is not wrong and my Vehicletwod got at least 2 object when I try run toDisplay, whats actually went wrong..

**Update:**

I just did this thanks to the valuable feedback I receive from the experts here.

at main.cpp

```
int main()
{
VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
vehicletwod[i] = new VehicleTWoD();
}

//some computation then I go to sort..

sort(&vehicletwod[0],&vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]);

for(int i=0;i<vehicleCounter;i++)
{
cout << vehicletwod->toDisplay() << endl;
}

}
```

The output remain the same, nothing sorted.. I not sure why..

this is the boolean operator I did at the VehicleTwoD.h

VehicleTwoD.h

```
public:
bool operator<(const VehicleTwoD&) const;
```

VehicleTwoD.cpp

```
bool VehicleTwoD::operator<(const VehicleTwoD& rhs) const
{
return area > rhs.area;
}
```

Nothing is sorted.. I would hope at least it sort in either descending or ascending..

I was wonder if theres a way I can allocate my VehicleTwoD array into a vector call sortVector, because after sort in ascending, I wanna sort in descending also.

so a reverse function in vector will be good to solve it.

**Any suggestion ? Thanks all the helpful and kind experts here!!**

Answer (score 3):

```
VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];
```

That just creates an array of references that point to an invalid memory location.

You need a loop or another way to allocate 100 valid references. Example:

```
for(int i=0;i < 100;i++)
{
  vehicletwod[i] = new VehicleTwoD() ;
}
```

And you have to remember to free those memory.

Comment: how do i free those memory, Thanks!

Comment: I updated my question with add in solutions posted here. but sort still does not sort anything.

Comment: In your overloaded operator, it looks like it should be: `return area < rhs.area`. But it depends on how your sort function works.

Comment: but the issue is nothing change, even if i put the wrong < or > it should at least sort ascending or descending. but the sort like do nothing and nothing change.

Comment: It may help to post the sort function.

Comment: I got the sort function at my question, sort(&vehicletwod[0],&vehicletwod[shapeCounter]);

Comment: I attached the code, the original one. As in case you confuse, shapetwod is the vehicletwod, and cross , rectangle, square is the child.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `vehicletwod[i]->toDisplay()` is UB because `vehicletwod[i]` (whatever `i` is) is never initialized.

`VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];` just creates an array of 100 **dangling pointers**.

I suggest you use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<VehicleTwoD>>` instead (since it appears your class is polymorphic and you want polymorphic behavior).

Answer (score 2):

There are many things which are wrong in your program.

```
VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];
```

creates an array of 100 uninitialized **pointers** to `VehicleTwoD`

```
sort(vehicletwod[0], vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]);
```

sorts the range defined by two pointers, `vehicletwod[0]` and `vehicletwod[vehicleCounter]`. As the array is not initialized, those pointers are garbage, so sorting would corrupt memory.

You might want the following

```
std::vector<VehicleTwoD> vehicletwod; // vector of instances
// initialize the vector
// ...
sort(vehicletwod.begin(), vehicletwod.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to what the others said here's a compilable example (updated for reverse sort/updated for static class compare function):

Instead of overloading the < operator you may want to consider making the sort
direction explicit, for instance by specifying static comparers as shown below.
I prefer this option because it allows you to document your intent.

in Vehicle.h:

```
#include <random>
class VehicleTwoD
{

    private:
        double area;
    public:
        VehicleTwoD() 
        {
            area = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
        }

        double toDisplay()
        {
            return area;
        }

        bool VehicleTwoD::operator<(const VehicleTwoD& rhs) const
        {
            return area > rhs.area;
        }
        static bool VehicleTwoD::greater(const VehicleTwoD &lhs, const VehicleTwoD &rhs) 
        {
            return lhs.area > rhs.area;
        }

        static bool VehicleTwoD::lesser(const VehicleTwoD &lhs, const VehicleTwoD &rhs) 
        {
            return lhs.area < rhs.area;
        }

};
```

and in main.cpp:

```
#include "Vehicle.h"    
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    std::vector<VehicleTwoD> vehicles(100);
    std::vector<VehicleTwoD>::iterator it;


    sort(vehicles.begin(), vehicles.end());
    for(it = vehicles.begin();  it != vehicles.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "Vehicle area -> " << it->toDisplay() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Press any key..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    // reverse sort - note that rbegin() rend() may be second-class citizens
    // depending on your compiler's implementation and that their use may therefore
    // be limited
    sort(vehicles.rbegin(), vehicles.rend());
    for(it = vehicles.begin();  it != vehicles.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "Vehicle area -> " << it->toDisplay() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Press any key..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    // or (document your intention)
    sort(vehicles.begin(), vehicles.end(), VehicleTwoD::greater);
    for(it = vehicles.begin();  it != vehicles.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "Vehicle area -> " << it->toDisplay() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Press any key..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    sort(vehicles.begin(), vehicles.end(), VehicleTwoD::lesser);
    for(it = vehicles.begin();  it != vehicles.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "Vehicle area -> " << it->toDisplay() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Press any key..." << std::endl;
    vehicles.clear();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hi the code as posted above will sort accurately. Post your actual (compilable) code so we can what the problem is. For reverse sort no need to allocate another vector. You can use the reverse iteror rbegin() and rend() to reverse sort order. See updated code above for an example.